# The variable from textField does not change each time the textfield changed?

Tags: java

I'm writing a code in java that connect to an ip address via sshxcue library.

the app has a JTextField and get the ip such as 192.168.1.101 and return it to ConnBean object.

The problem is: when I enter IP for the first time the app works perfectly but when I change the IP in textfield the ConnBean object still use the IP address that I entered at the first time! how can I solve it?

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String ip = input.getText();
        output.setText(input.getText());
        // Initialize a ConnBean object, parameter list is ip, username, password
        ConnBean cb = new ConnBean(ip , "username","password");
        // Put the ConnBean instance as parameter for SSHExec static method getInstance(ConnBean) to retrieve a singleton SSHExec instance
        ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);          
        // Connect to server
        ssh.connect();
    }
});
```

I put a textArea as output it return correctly. but ConnBean object not. why?

Comment: If it's a singleton, getInstance() probably ignores what you pass as parameter the second time you call it, and returns the instance that has been created before. Anyway, it's impossible to answer without guessing, because we don't have the code of SSHExec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSHExec is implemented as a singleton, and if its instance already exists, it returns the same instance.

However, you could try to change the host in the ConnBean that you passed to SSHExec, as it has public accessors for that, is using a reference of it, not a copy. Create the ConnBean outside of the anonymous listener, and just set the IP in it from inside the listener.

Somewhere (where it won't go out of scope, like a field), define

```
ConnBean cb = null;
```

Then define your actionListener as:

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String ip = input.getText();
        output.setText(input.getText());
        // Initialize a ConnBean object, parameter list is ip, username, password
        if ( cb == null ) {
            cb = new ConnBean(ip , "username","password");
        } else {
            cb.setHost(ip);
        }

        // Put the ConnBean instance as parameter for SSHExec static method getInstance(ConnBean) to retrieve a singleton SSHExec instance
        ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);          
        // Connect to server
        ssh.connect();
    }
});
```

Of course, make sure you have disconnected before trying to connect again.

[Source code of ConnBean](https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/source/browse/trunk/sshxcute/src/net/neoremind/sshxcute/core/ConnBean.java)

[Source code of SSHExec](https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/source/browse/trunk/sshxcute/src/net/neoremind/sshxcute/core/SSHExec.java)

Comment: I edited my answer and added the code to explain. It's important to keep using the same ConnBean object, rather than use `new ConnBean(...)` because SSHExec maintains a reference to the first ConnBean object that was passed to it.